# Populate ArrayList in constructor with scanner input -Java

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

I'm working on a programming project and I have a little knowledge of Java. I can't seem to figure out what this professor is looking for.

You will create a Java class called `ArrayWorks`. The constructor will ask the user how many numbers they are entering, then retrieving those numbers from the user. The numbers will be placed into an `ArrayList` created by the constructor. The `ArrayList` is the lone attribute of the
`ArrayWorks` class.

You will then write following methods:

1. size : This method returns the size of the ArrayList attribute
2. ave : This method calculates and returns the average of the numbers on the array. Note
   that the average will not ALWAYS be a whole number, so use an appropriate return type.
3. Max : Returns the highest value on the array
4. Min : Returns the lowest value on the array

What I got:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayWorks{

ArrayWorks (int inputs, ArrayList<Integer> nums){
this.inputs = inputs;
this.nums = nums;
}  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println("please enter how many numbers you have to enter!");
    int numOfInputs = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Now enter the numbers!");
    for(int i = numOfInputs; i>0; i--){
      nums.add(sc.nextInt());
    }
  }
  int inputs;
  ArrayList<Integer> nums;
  int size;
  int max;
  int min;
  double ave;


  public int getSize(){
    size = nums.size();
    return size;
  }

  public double ave(){
    int sum = 0;
    for (Integer i : nums) { 
      sum += i;
    }

    double average = sum / nums.size();

    return average;
  }

  public int max(){
    for(Integer i: nums) {
    if(i > max) max = i;
}
    return max;
  }

  public int min(){
    for(Integer i: nums) {
    if(i < min) min = i;
}
    return min;
  }

}
```

problem being I don't know how I can satisfy his need for the constructor to be the one taking in the inputs.

Thank you very much for the help Thrasher! if anyone has more input please let me know!

Comment: show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: You have to create a class with an arrayList of numbers attribute and a constructor which receive as parameter an ArrayList. Then in your main class ask how many numbers you want to enter. After that, loop over that amount and finally create your arrayWorks with the ArrayList you previously filled.

Comment: I think thrasher has the right idea! thanks ill try to implement that

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer for your professor requirements, also i suggest to ask user input on main class and use the constructor just to set the parameters, because you can use your class on any kind of user interface. I also worked on some methods (size, ave, max, min) that you may need in the future.

### ArrayWorks:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayWorks
{
    private List < Integer > numberList;

    public ArrayWorks ()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> mylist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.print("Enter number of iterations: ");
        int numberOfIterations = sc.nextInt ( );

        //Iterate user input number
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print("Enter Integer number " + (i+1) +": ");
            int num = sc.nextInt();
            mylist.add(num);
        }
        System.out.println ( "Finished" );

        this.numberList = mylist;
    }

    public List < Integer > getNumberList ( )
    {
        return numberList;
    }

    public void setNumberList ( List < Integer > numberList )
    {
        this.numberList = numberList;
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return this.numberList.size ( );
    }

    public float ave()
    {
        int size = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < this.numberList.size ( ); i++)
        {
            sum += numberList.get ( i );
            size++;
        }

        return (float) sum/size;
    }

    public int max()
    {
        int max = 0;
        int current = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < this.numberList.size ( ); i++)
        {
            current = numberList.get ( i );
            if ( current > max )
            {
                max = current;
            }

        }

        return max;
    }

    public int min()
    {

        int min = numberList.get ( 0 );
        int current = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < this.numberList.size ( ); i++)
        {
            current = numberList.get ( i );
            if ( current < min )
            {
                min = current;
            }

        }

        return min;
    }   

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "ArrayWorks [numberList=" + numberList + "]";
    }

}
```

### Console:

```
public class mainProgram
{

    public static void main ( String [ ] args )
    {

        //Create your ArrayWorks
        ArrayWorks myArrayWork = new ArrayWorks ();
        System.out.println ( "toString: " + myArrayWork.toString ( ) );
        System.out.println ( "size: " + myArrayWork.size() );
        System.out.println ( "avg: " + myArrayWork.ave ( ) );
        System.out.println ( "max: " + myArrayWork.max ( ) );
        System.out.println ( "min: " + myArrayWork.min ( ) );


    }

}
```

### Example input/output:

> Enter number of iterations: 3
>
> Enter Integer number 1: 10
>
> Enter Integer number 2: 5
>
> Enter Integer number 3: 1
>
> Finished
>
> toString: ArrayWorks [numberList=[10, 5, 1]]
>
> size: 3
>
> avg: 5.3333335
>
> max: 10
>
> min: 1

Comment: thank you very much for the response. I've been working away and eventually came to this! (You are correct max min and size were other methods he was asking for) *updated in post*